# How to automatically sync files drive with onedrive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, sync

I recently dual booted my pc with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10.

Ubuntu allows me to access windows 10 files which are present in D drive..

With this, I can access any file present in D drive on ubuntu.. But I want the file to get copied to the onedrive folder so that I gets synced automatically..

Had there been gui for onedrive on linux, there would have been no need for this. But sadly its not available.

Is there any workaround??

Answer (score 0):

Use this [OneDrive for Linux](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive), doesn't even need GUI.

Comment: The skilion onedrive client is not developed anymore. But there is the new onedrive client for linux, which should be available on Ubuntu with `apt-get install onedrive`.

Answer (score 0):

onedrive -m

Leave teminal open

Comment: Doesn't the current version of onedrive package on Ubuntu enable the onedrive service by default? May be you need to run `systemctl --user enable onedrive` to enable it?